# There are many red and black spots in my photos,what are those?

Tags: noise, canon-60d

[image]

I am using canon 60d for more than 1year.few months ago i suddenly saw these dots were appeared in my photos.i have tried manual sensor cleaning several number of times,but this didn't work for me.what do i need to do to get rid of this problem? A photo of the camera screen is given below....

Comment: Do the spots show up when you view the images on a computer? Or only on the camera's LCD screen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your camera to service center. Unfortunately you can't solve this problem by yourself. Its so called *hot pixels*. I have them too. Before repairing I used RAW converter for photos

Comment: There _are_ approaches to working around them — as you mention, if you shoot all RAW, it can be a non-issue. Some cameras, but I don't think the 60D, have a built-in function to map them out.